how to add all thing in slice to an only one string
hello every body i was coding about create a map and on that map we have 2 thing name of book and number of book and i stuck in one thing if name of book is look like this "Harry Potter" only my code add Harry and i think to add all thing after Harry in my slice but golang give error and said you cant add slice to map only you can add one string thing and i dont know how to fix it
this is my code
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

        //how much data you want add and delete
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    scanner.Scan()
    num, _ := strconv.Atoi(scanner.Text())
    mymap := make(map[int]string)

    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {

        scanner.Scan()
        info := strings.Fields(scanner.Text())

        //if he want to add datas
        if info[0] == "ADD" {
            var z, _ = strconv.Atoi(info[1])
            mymap[z] = info[2]

            //if he want remove datas
        } else if info[0] == "REMOVE" {
            x := info[1]
            var z, _ = strconv.Atoi(x)
            delete(mymap, z)

        }

    }
    fmt.Println(mymap)
}


so i do
mymap[z] = info[2:] 
but its not work and this is my problem

info[2:] will return a string slice when your map expects a complete string.
To resolve the error and accept the full name of the Book, you might want to join the slice obtained from info[2:] to form a full string.
Thus, using strings.Join(info[2:], " ") will solve the issue.
updated code piece:
mymap[z] = strings.Join(info[2:], " ")


info will be a []string e.g. {"ADD", "1", "Harry", "Potter"} and you want to convert info[2:] into a string (i.e. "Harry Potter") with the elements separated by spaces (partly reversing strings.Fields). strings.Join is probably the simplest approach (playground):
func main() {

    testInput := []string{ // simulate input
        "ADD 1 Harry Potter",
        "ADD 1 Harry Potter",
        "ADD 1 Lord of the rings",
        "REMOVE 2 Harry Potter",
    }

    mymap := make(map[int]string)

    for _, command := range testInput {
        info := strings.Fields(command)
        //if he want to add datas
        if info[0] == "ADD" {
            var z, _ = strconv.Atoi(info[1])
            mymap[z] = strings.Join(info[2:], " ")

            //if he want remove datas
        } else if info[0] == "REMOVE" {
            x := info[1]
            var z, _ = strconv.Atoi(x)
            delete(mymap, z)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(mymap)
}

Note: The resulting string may not exactly match your input (e.g. multiple spaces would be lost) but this may not matter for your use case.
I would note that your code is probably not doing what you want. Consider

ADD 1 Harry Potter
ADD 1 Lion Witch
ADD 1 Lord of the rings

Will result in map[1:Lord of the rings] (probably not what you want).
